# NameError: uninitialized constant Roo::Excelx::Zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, roo, roo-gem

I am using ruby 2.2.1 and rails 4.2.1.

I am using following gems.

```
roo (2.0.1)
roo-xls (1.0.0)
rubyzip (1.1.7)
```

I have written a rake task as follows.

check_roo.rake

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'roo-xls'
require 'roo'

desc "desc"
task :check_roo => :environment do |task, args|
  xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new("#{Rails.root}/v15_Data.xlsx")
end
```

Output for bundle exec rake check_roo:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Roo::Excelx::Zip
/home/abhimanyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@newerp/gems/roo-2.0.1/lib/roo/excelx.rb:412:in `process_zipfile'
/home/abhimanyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@newerp/gems/roo-2.0.1/lib/roo/excelx.rb:100:in `initialize'
/home/abhimanyu/Documents/projects/abc/lib/tasks/check_roo.rake:9:in `new'
/home/abhimanyu/Documents/projects/abc/lib/tasks/check_roo.rake:9:in `block in <top (required)>'
```

But when I run the following command in rails console it works fine.

```
xlsx = Roo::Excelx.new("#{Rails.root}/v15_Data.xlsx")
```

Output:

```
<#Roo::Excelx:320135634 @tmpdirs @tmpdir @filename @comments_files @rels_files @sheet_files @workbook @sheet_names @sheets @styles @shared_strings @sheets_by_name @options @cell @cell_type @cells_read @first_row @last_row @first_column @last_column @header_line>
```

Not able to understand why the same command works in console but not inside a rake file.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you type `bundle exec rake your_task` does it work?